# Do minimum spanning trees drawn on points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ always have non-intersecting edges?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, discrete-optimization, planar-graphs

## Preamble

This question is motivated by the question [*"Embedded minimum spanning trees for visualizing effects of dimensionality reduction?"*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/587801/embedded-minimum-spanning-trees-for-visualizing-effects-of-dimensionality-reduct).

Suppose I were to begin with a collection of points $X = \{x_1, \cdots, x_n \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and computed a minimum spanning tree on these points with edges drawn as the straight line segments.

I know that trees are always planar graphs, but that doesn't mean that all choices of embedding don't have intersections of the line segments representing the edges.

## Example

Below is a sample from a pair of IID standard normal data variables. I've empirically inducted that the resulting MST always has a planar embedding from looking at many such plots.

[image]

### Example Code

```
from itertools import combinations

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

X = np.random.normal(size=1000).reshape((500,2))
pos = {i:X[i] for i in range(X.shape[0])}

g = nx.Graph()
for comb in combinations(range(X.shape[0]),r=2):
    g.add_edge(*comb, weight=np.linalg.norm(X[comb[0]] - X[comb[1]]))

g = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(g)

nx.draw(g, pos, node_size=20)
plt.show()
```

## Question

Are the line segments drawn on the plane guaranteed to be non-intersecting?

Comment: Are you talking about the euclidean minimum spanning tree?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. If you have two crossing edges, consider the four vertices involved. Each of the two other ways to insert the pair of edges should be shorter, and one of them will still be a tree.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know the term [Euclidean MST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree), but the description on wiki suggests that is what I am talking about. Furthermore it says that *"Each edge lies in an empty region of the plane..."* which sounds promising.

Comment: The Euclidean MST is a subgraph of the Delaunay triangulation which is a planar graph therefore it is indeed planar.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Right, we know that all trees are planar: they *can* be embedded on the plane in a non-intersecting way. It looks like your suggestion goes further that the Euclidean MST is a [planar embedding of the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph), right?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis I think you have the answer. Please post it as one so I can give you credit.

Comment: @Galen That is correct, yeah. It doesn't make sense to talk about planarity in general when considering trees since, as you said, all trees are planar graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a summary of the discussion in the comments posted as an answer:

The [Eucledean MST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree) is always a subgraph of the Delaunay triangulation. This can be proved easily by arguing with contradiction:

If an edge $e$ between points $A$ and $B$ of the EMST does not belong in the Delaunay triangulation then, by considering the circle $C(e)$ with diameter $e$, we could find another point $D$ inside $C(E)$. This allows us to replace the edge $e$ with another suitably chosen edge $e'$ in a way that the total length of the edges decreases, a contradiction.

Now since the Delaunay triangulation is an embedded planar graph the same holds for the EMST.