# Can we algorithmically map a Delaunay tesselation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a planar embedding in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: planar-graphs, tessellations

## Preamble

Suppose I have a finite collection of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I compute a Delaunay tesselation on them. In this $n$-dimensional space the straight-line edges are non-intersecting line segments. I am under the impression that there always exists a map $T: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ that would arrange the points such that the resulting embedding of the Delaunay tesselation on these points would be planar.

## Examples

This is the projected Delaunay triangulation for Ronald Fisher's Iris data, which is a collection of points in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The red scatter shows points of intersection for the lines representing edges of the Delaunay tesselation. This visually makes clear that the transform I chose does not produce a planar embedding. The transform was a linear transform via principal component analysis, which I had no expectation would work for this purpose but would allow me to develop such a figure.

[image]

As another illustration, here is an embedding of the same Delaunay tesselation using tSNE.

[image]

## Question

For a given collection of points, is there an algorithm for constructing map that will provide a planar embedding of the corresponding Delaunay tesselation?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526303/do-minimum-spanning-trees-drawn-on-points-in-mathbbr2-always-have-non-inte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your impression is not correct. Delaunay tesselations are equivalent to polytopes inscribed in the sphere, and so you are asking whether the 1-skeleton of an inscribed polytope is always a planar graph. That this is false follows, for example, from the work of Gonska and Ziegler:

*Gonska, Bernd; Ziegler, Günter M.*, [**Inscribable stacked polytopes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/advgeom-2013-0014), Adv. Geom. 13, No. 4, 723-740 (2013). [ZBL1288.52007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1288.52007).